# Easy way to add drop down menu with 1 - 100 without doing 100 different options?

Tags: html, forms

I was just wondering if there was a simple shortcut to add options to a dropdown menu for the numbers 1 to 100 instead of having to do the following:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
```

etc. all the way to 100?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not with plain HTML I'm afraid.

You could use some jQuery to do this though:

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $(".1-100");
    for (i=1;i<=100;i++){
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }
});​
```

**[-- SEE DEMO --](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/preYN/)**

You can download jQuery **[here](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)**

Comment: that would work great, which jQuery language do I embed that in? <script src="/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> etc?

Comment: @LukeTetrabyte That's the one, as long as its an up-to-date library

Answer (score 20):

Not with pure HTML as far as I know.

But with JS or PHP or another scripting language such as JSP, you can do it very easily with a for loop.

Example in PHP:

```
<select>
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
        <?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 10):

Are you using JavaScript or jQuery besides the html? If you are, you can do something like:

HTML:

```
<select id='some_selector'></select>​
```

jQuery:

```
var select = '';
for (i=1;i<=100;i++){
    select += '<option val=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>';
}
$('#some_selector').html(select);
```

As you can [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/qGNPT/).

Another option for compatible browsers instead of select, you can use is HTML5's `input type=number`:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1">
```

Answer (score 10):

In Html5, you can now use

```
<form>
<input type="number" min="1" max="100">
</form>
```

Comment: But the user can type any value on the box with the keyboard.

Comment: How did this even get any upvotes?  This is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I see this is old but...
I dont know if you are looking for code to generate the numbers/options every time its loaded or not. But I use an excel or open office calc page and place use the auto numbering all the time. It may look like this...

| `<option>`  |  1  |  `</option>` |

Then I highlight the cells in the row and drag them down until there are 100 or the number that I need. I now have code snippets that I just refer back to.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery One-liners:

ES6 + jQuery:

```
$('#select').append([...Array(100).keys()].map((i,j) => `< option >${i}</option >`))
```

Lodash + jQuery:

```
$('#select').append(_.range(100).map(function(i,j){ return $('<option>',{text:i})}))
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has said, there isn't one in html; however, you could use [PUG/Jade](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html). In fact I do this often.

It would look something like this:

```
select
  - var i = 1
  while i <= 100
    option=i++
```

This would produce:
[image: screenshot of htmltojade.org]

Answer (score -3):

Just Type in an online Compiler C++ and copy and Paste it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    for(int i=18;i<=60;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"<option value="<<i<<">"<<i<<"</option>";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.