# HTML & PHP - get index of selected value in dropdown list

Tags: php, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a select dropdown list just like this:

```
<select name="type" id="type">
<option>First option</option>
```

And so on...and I have more than 100 of these options.
How can I, through PHP, retrieve the INDEX of the selected value, and not the selected value itself (For example is someone selects "First Option" I'd like to get the value "1" (or 0), instead of "First Option).
I know I could just add a "value=1" but it would take a lot of time to add this for all the elements so I'd like to know if there is a quicker, easier method.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This can be done with JQuery, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10142694/5152519

Comment: use a `foreach` with array keys

Comment: So there are `100` of options fixed? A simple `for-loop` could be implemented too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the values and count, what you get ... i do not think, this is a good way. I do not think, there is a quicker, easier method to do this but using the "value" attributes.

```
<option value="1">First option</option>
<option value="2">Second option</option>
<option value="3">Third option</option>
...
```

Comment: *"and I have more than 100 of these options."* and *"I know I could just add a "value=1" but it would take a lot of time to add this for all the elements so I'd like to know if there is a quicker, easier method."* is what the OP wrote. This will require a `foreach` and array keys.

Comment: IMHO is there no better (or "safer") way to get the index. Any way with jQuery or JS requires JS to be active. With just a "value" added, you are "rock solid", so the value is working in any environment that can handle standard html.

Comment: what does it have to do with JS? OP asked for and tagged as PHP.

Comment: Just want to answer the question "ahead" ... i edited my answer.

Comment: The OP specifically stated *"and I have more than 100 of these options."* and *"I know I could just add a "value=1" but it would take a lot of time to add this for all the elements so I'd like to know if there is a quicker, easier method."* - what part of that is to not understand? Your answer does exactly what the OP does NOT want to do.

Comment: *"Just want to answer the question "ahead""* - Kind of a *foot in the door* type of answer then.

Comment: He asked, if there is a quicker and easier method to do this. My optinion is: no, there is no easier or "better" way to do this but inserting value attributes.

Comment: @Paladin76 yes there is and have already stated that under the OP's question and this answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Iterating twice over Strings is no good way to process user input, if you have the way to do this in away with indicies. I do not know the _exact_ problem, but spoken in general, one should better use unique values to represent each option, so that the input can easily be parsed by his backend.